# How to connect to database using single variable in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two dimensional array with key and value

```
   Array ( 
     [conduct] => 
       Array ( [databaseName] => conduct 
               [databaseKey] => 'localhost', 'root', '','conduct' )   
     [conducttest] => 
       Array ( [databaseName] => conducttest 
               [databaseKey] => 'localhost', 'root', '','conducttest' ) 
     [test] => 
       Array ( [databaseName] => test 
               [databaseKey] => 'localhost', 'root', '','test' ) 
)
```

I have a dropdown in my form and which contains database name when user  choose any database name I want to connect with that database. So for that I have create two dimension array and store database name and it's connection string.

When form is submit that time I have sent those name and connection string to php.

**Here my PHP Code :**

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}
    include "includes/timezone.php";

    $currentURL = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
    $currentURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
    $url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $url = $currentURL.str_replace("/admin/connTo.php","",$url);

    $key = isset($_REQUEST['key']) ? $_REQUEST['key'] : "";
    $dbname = isset($_REQUEST['name']) ? $_REQUEST['name'] : "";

    $conTo = mysqli_connect($key);

    if (!mysqli_select_db($conTo, $dbname)) {
        die("Error : ".mysqli_error($conTo));
    }

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    mysqli_query($conTo,"SET character_set_results='utf8'");
    mysqli_query($conTo,"SET NAMES utf8");
    mysqli_query($conTo,"SET GLOBAL time_zone='+05:30'");   
    mysqli_query($conTo,"SET time_zone='+05:30'");  
    mysqli_query($conTo,"SET system_time_zone='+05:30'");   
    mysqli_query($conTo,"SET GLOBAL max_connect_errors=100000");    
    mysqli_query($conTo,"SET GLOBAL max_connections=100000");   
    mysqli_query($conTo,"SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=100");  
    mysqli_query($conTo,"SET GLOBAL max_user_connections=100000");

    if(isset($conTo) && isset($_REQUEST['key'])){
        echo "1";
    } else if(isset($_REQUEST['key'])){
        echo "0";
    }
?>
```

I am 100% sure that $key gets proper connection string but my code display below errors:

**Warning**:  mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/conductexam/admin/connTo.php** on line **13**

**Warning**:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/conductexam/admin/connTo.php** on line **13**

**Warning**:  mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/conductexam/admin/connTo.php** on line **15**

**Warning**:  mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/conductexam/admin/connTo.php** on line **16**

But when I change to

```
$conTo = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','conduct');
```

It's work fine. How?

Can anybody help me? I really appreciate for your help. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: it's a horrible practice to send your connection that way.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your question, however this line:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}
```

Should not be used.  If you are using sessions, then you need a session_start() at the top of your script.

As to your question, you misunderstand mysqli_connect.  It requires parameters, not a single string or even an array.

I'm not clear if you are trying to indicate that you are using javascript to pass those parameters into a form variable but that sounds like a bad idea.  Most people would have the credentials in an included script.

However, let's assume you were to continue with your existing scheme:

```
$key = isset($_REQUEST['key']) ? $_REQUEST['key'] : "";
$params = explode(',', $key);
$conTo = mysqli_connect($params[0], $params[1], $params[2], $params[3]);
```

This code actually has a chance to work, in the same way that it works when you pass the parameters as string constants.

Comment: I assure you that is not the case.  It requires at least 3 parameters, and optionally an additional 3.  They can all be php string variables.  See the manual page:  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php